# SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### 解決しました。(今なぜか問題なくブラウザにアクセスすることができました。大変すみません。)

scaffoldを昨日終えてブラウザも動いていたのですが、先ほどrails s 後、ブラウザにアクセスしようとすると以下の表示が出てブラウザにアクセスすることができません。どのようにすればいいでしょうか。宜しくお願いします。（Windows10 home / ruby 2.4.4 / rails 5.2.0)

(0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98

Comment: 解決された場合は、ご自身で回答を記入してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。(何もしていないのですが今朝、なぜか問題なくブラウザにアクセスすることができました。大変すみません。)